# Spring Boot: Autowiring app credentials within custom autoconfiguration bean returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working with a custom AWS Simple System Management client just to avoid the original from using the default AWS authentication chain, so I placed my class in `/META-INF/spring.factories` and excluded the original from being autconfigured in `bootstrap.yml` . What I'm facing right now is to get the credentials from `application.yml` and pass them to my new conf, but when I try to autowire them all I get is `null`. I wonder if there is any way to achieve it

Here is the code:

```
package es.example;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.*;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.credentials")
@Data
public class CustomAWSSSMAuthProperties {
  private String accessKey;
  private String secretKey;
}
```

```
package es.example;

import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.*;

@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomAWSSSMAuthProperties.class)
public class CustomAWSSSMClient extends AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient {

  @Autowired
  private CustomAWSSSMAuthProperties customProperties;

  public CustomAWSSSMClient() {
    String accessKey = customProperties.getAccessKey();
    String secretKey = customProperties.getSecretKey();
  }
}
```

`/META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
es.example.CustomAWSSSMClient
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
es.example.CustomAWSSSMClient
```

`bootstrap.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}
  autoconfigure.exclude: com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient
```

Many thanks

Comment: How should an object that is being constructed be autowired? Autowiring will only occur **after** an object has been constructed, so this will simply not work.

Answer (score 0):

`@ConfigurationProperties` does not create a bean like `@Configuration` or `@Component` does. In your case `CustomAWSSSMAuthProperties` type bean/object will not be instantiated in the Spring context.

Generally `@ConfigurationProperties` is used with `@Configuration` or `@Bean` to bind the some properties to the bean.

You can annotate `CustomAWSSSMAuthProperties` with `@Configuration` to fix the issue.

Comment: Is the autowired object null or are the fields of the object null?

Comment: The object is null, indeed